# Can SVG filters be applied similarly to the Anonymous Function?

Tags: xml, svg, svg-filters

So I was wondering, in SVG, filters have to be applied like this:

```
<defs>
<filter id="foo">
<!-- let's pretend that it does something -->
</filter>
</defs>
<g filter="url(#foo)">
<!-- some graphic elements - or maybe instead of a <g> element it's a singular graphic -->
</g>
```

Now, that's a *lot* of extra weight to the file, especially when the image has, for example, one filter that's only used once. However, in JavaScript or PHP, something similar like this:

```javascript
someFunctionWithCallback(foo);

function foo(bar) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Can be simplified like this:

```javascript
someFunctionWithCallback(function(bar) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Is there any way to do the same kind of thing in SVG? E.g. declare a filter inside the element that I use it on, while eliminating weight and the need to store it for later?

Comment: You could make the filter into a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I know about those. Unfortunately, it either doesn't work in this case, or I'm doing it wrong, as well as the fact that it isn't all that good at eliminating the bulk of the file, which is, well, the main point of the JS anonymous function.

Comment: You know about [CSS filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty)?

Answer (score -1):

A typical filter is a couple hundred bytes. The average generated SVG has tens of kilobytes of crap that you can optimize out. And an average commercial page load has hundreds of kilobytes of image weight and javascript that can be optimized out.

Don't spend time optimizing stuff that doesn't matter.

Comment: By that logic, the JavaScript anonymous functions shouldn't exist; they're there because it makes the code _easier to understand_. That's exactly why I'm asking this: I handcode all of my SVG's (okay, except a little bit) and I care about the difficulty to understand it. A filtered element makes a lot more sense by using simply @RobertLongson's `blur(25px)` than if it's a reference to a completely different part of the file.

Comment: that's not the rationale you stated in your question - which was to reduce file weight

Comment: Well… it's more just making it simpler. Though I guess the question might have been vague